# from . import models works, but import models doesn't

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, import

I'm working on a webproject and using Django. In my `views.py` file I want to access the database for which I want to import my `models`.

Here's my directory structure:

```
├── project  
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   ├── settings.py  
│   ├── urls.py  
│   └── wsgi.py  
├── app  
│   ├── admin.py  
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   ├── models.py  
│   ├── tests.py  
│   └── views.py  
├── manage.py
```

In my `views.py` I'm doing `import models`, but I'm getting an `importError`. Although `from . import models` works.

Why?

But the following works without any error:

```
├── __init__.py
├── mod1.py
└── mod2.py
```

mod1.py

```
import mod2

print(mod2.foo())
```

mod2.py

```
def foo():
    return "Hello"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of `import models` is that you don't know whether its an absolute import or a relative import. models could a module in python's path, or a package in the current module.

**This is quite annoying when a local package has the same name as a python standard library package.**

You can do `from __future__ import absolute_import` which turns off implicit relative imports altogether. It is described, including with this justification about ambiguity, in [PEP 328](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328). I believe Python 3000 has implicit relative imports turned off completely.

You still can do relative imports, but you have to do them explicitly, like this:

`from . import models`

Hence, relative imports `from . import models` work, whereas absolute imports, `import models` don't.

Comment: But if I make a separate package, with two modules, and then do a relative import, it works?

Answer (score 7):

In order to use an absolute import, you need to refer to the full package.sibling combo:

```
import app.models
from app import models
from app.models import mymodel
```

However, explicit relative imports are an acceptable alternative to absolute imports:

```
from . import models
from .models import mymodel
```

You should really [read PEP-8 on imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) for a great explanation about importing packages.

Comment: But if I make a separate package, with two modules, and then do a relative import, it works?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: That's not a new package (there are no directories). Both of those are at the project root, so you can import them directly.

Comment: But in my case also both `views.py` and `models.py` are at the project root of package `app`.

Comment: That's not the project root. `app` is a package. `views.py` and `models.py` are "siblings".

Comment: But in my second case, doesn't putting a `__init__.py` file also make it a package?