# Can't find module I made

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

in sub folder, I am coding a python file(/test_utils/test_manager.py).

```
import csv
from models import TestQuestions
from database import db
from main import serendipity_app
```

And in that file, I am using modules(database, models) in above folder.
But when I execute main.py with 'python main.py'
python said ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'.

I don't understand why this error occured.

the image below is my project structure.

[image]

Comment: Try something like, 'from folder import Model', (folder - test manager, model - TestQuestions)

Comment: I don't understand what you said, but I tried. And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're working on file test_manager.py, import models like, `from projectName.models import TestQuestions`.
make sure you're using the correct path for models directory
[from . import models works, but import models doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982556/from-import-models-works-but-import-models-doesnt][1])

Comment: I've updated the answer..  if this won't work, share some sample code of models file, issue could be something different..I'm assuming TestQuestioins/db are the classes in that models/database files

Comment: class TestQuestions(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test_questions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    test_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    question_number = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    question_string = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    question_tag = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True) 
    is_reverse_scoring = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder  try the answers in these..

Comment: I just tried to import os, sys. and then sys.path.append etc. and then. I got other errors. It's ridiculous. Even a file I didn't import run...